# How can I turn the null character into a blank character in my Java TicTacToe program?

Tags: java

At the moment, I have working code for a simple Tic Tac Toe program written in java. The only problem, as you'll see below, is that the null character (\u0000) is being printed instead of an open space when my board is displayed.

My professor told us to write this program in such a way that null spaces are detected and to fill them with either X or O, which I did.

Now, I would like to be able to change the null character from appearing as 00 to just a blank space since the format is incorrect otherwise.

I already tried simply erasing the '\u0000' character and replacing it with a ' ' character but then my board doesn't show up at all. Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

  public class TicTacToe
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

     char[][] board = new char[3][3];

     while (true) {

        makeCompMove(board, 'X');

        displayBoard(board);
        if(isWon('X', board)) {
           System.out.println("\n\nComputer won!");
           System.exit(1);
        }

        else if (isDraw(board)) {
           System.out.println("\n\nDraw Game! No winner");
           System.exit(2);
        }

        makeAMove(board, 'O');
        displayBoard(board);

        if (isWon('O', board)) {
           System.out.println("\n\nPlayer won!");
           System.exit(3);
        }
        else if (isDraw(board)) {
           System.out.println("\n\nDraw Game! No winner");
           System.exit(4);
        }
     }
  }

  public static void displayBoard(char[][] board) 
  {

     for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
        {
           System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
           System.out.print("|" + "  " + board[k][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");

     }
        for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
     {
        System.out.print("-");
     }

  }

  public static void makeAMove(char[][] board, char o)
  {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     while(true)
     {
        System.out.print("\n\nYour turn. Enter a row and col(0,1 or 2): ");
        int row = input.nextInt();
        int col = input.nextInt();
        if(row > 2 || row < 0 || col > 2 || col < 0)
        {
           System.out.println("Incorrect Input. Try Again!");
           continue;
        }
        if(board[row][col] == '\u0000')
        {
                System.out.print("\n You (O) have made your move...\n\n");
           board[row][col] = 'O';
                break;
        }
        else
           System.out.println("Incorrect Input. Try Again!");
     }
  }

    public static void makeCompMove(char[][] board, char x)
  {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Computer (X) has made his move...\n");
     while(true)
     {
        int row = (int)(Math.random()*3);
        int col = (int)(Math.random()*3);

            if(board[row][col] == '\u0000')
        {
           board[row][col] = x;
           break;
        }
     }
        System.out.println();
    }

 public static boolean isDraw(char[][] board)
  {
     for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
     {
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
           if(board[row][col] == '\u0000')
           {
              return false;
           }
        }
     }
     return true;
  }

  public static boolean isWon(char x, char[][] board)
  {
    // Check Rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if (x == board[i][0] && x == board[i][1] && x == board[i][2]) 
                return true;

    // Check Columns
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            if (x == board[0][j] && x == board[1][j] && x == board[2][j]) 
                return true;

    // Check first diagonal
        if (x == board[0][0] && x == board[1][1] && x == board[2][2]) 
            return true;

    // Check second diagonal
        if (x == board[0][2] && x == board[1][1] && x == board[2][0]) 
            return true;

    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change any of code You Just Check before display

in displayBoard use like this

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if(board[k][j]=='\u0000')
    System.out.print("|" + "     ");
    else
    System.out.print("|" + "  " + board[k][j] + "  ");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the two-dimensional array are set to the null character when the array is initialized.  If you want to convert them all to a space, then iterate over them all and replace the character with a space.

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        board[i][j] = ' ';
    }
}
```

If the place is never used, then it will have a space instead of the null character in it.  Do this *before* you use the array.

Comment: Wow that was too easy. Thank you very much sir!